# Can't rewrite <option> text in Safari/Chrome when <!DOCTYPE html> present

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to dynamically change the text a user sees in a `<select>` dropdown. The below works fine if I remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag. But Safari and Chrome don't cooperate with the `<!DOCTYPE html>` in place. And unfortunately, it's not optional in my situation.

Adding `id=`'s to the `<option>` tags and using `document.getElementById` avoids the problem, but sadly I can't use that either. This script has to work in the page as is, so I have to go through `getElementsByTagName`.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<select>
  <option label="Hi" value="1">Hello</option>
  <option label="Bye" value="2">Goodbye</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].innerHTML = "Aloha";
   document.getElementsByTagName("option")[1].innerHTML = "Shalom";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have `label` attributes there when you have option's value and text in place? You either set the `label` property instead of `innerHTML` or just remove the `label` attributes.

Comment: Use `selectElement.options[index].value=...` or `selectElement.options[index].text=...` to change the content.

Comment: Good question, why is the label there?? You'd have to ask the guy who wrote the page (or rather, the rinky-dink PHP that generates it).

Modifying `.label` works in Safari/Chrome, but not Firefox. I was hoping for a single solution, but maybe I'll just have to modify both `.label` and `.innerHTML` (or `.text`).

As for `.text`, neither it nor `.innerHTML` works in Safari/Chrome with the `<!DOCTYPE html>` in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Option relabel</title>
</head>
<body>

<select>
  <option label="Hi" value="1">Hello</option>
  <option label="Bye" value="2">Goodbye</option>
</select>

<script>
   var ops=document.getElementsByTagName("option");
   ops[0].removeAttribute('label');
   ops[1].removeAttribute('label');
   ops[0].text ="Aloha";
   ops[1].text="Shalom";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should either set the label property instead of innerHTML or just remove the label attributes. This should help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I can't remove the `label` attributes, have to work with the HTML as-is. As I said in my comment to Fabricio, setting the `label` property works in Safari/Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: @Jonathan, Firefox does not support attribute label as you can see it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp). 
For Firefox update the innerHTML.

Comment: Right, so the question is: is there a unified way to do this, one that's supported across the board.

Comment: not really. I would suggest you to update both attributes (label, innerHTML).